# Why in node, child_process `spawn` has no killSignal option but `spawnSync` has?

Tags: node.js, process

Additionally, how to spawn a child process that ignore `SIGTERM` and can only be killed by `SIGKILL`?

Comment: Have you a concrete application in mind ? Or some example to clarify what you actually want to do ?

Comment: Basically i want to have enhance https://github.com/sindresorhus/noop-process to have a option to create a process that can only be killed be `SIGKILL` and used later by my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this option is associated with the `timeout` option.

In `spawn` you have to decide when you kill the process.

Example: ([from doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal))

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const grep = spawn('grep', ['ssh']);

grep.on('close', (code, signal) => {
  console.log(
    `child process terminated due to receipt of signal ${signal}`);
});

// Send SIGHUP to process
grep.kill('SIGHUP');
```

Comment: Thanks! so there is no way to ignore `SIGTERM` for `spawn`ed child process?

Comment: the command you are running should not support SIGTERM, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21660539/1194525